# Linking with a static library

Tags: c, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I am having trouble in linking with a static library I created. Here is my directory structure:

```
test
├── b.c
├── b.o
├── i.h
├── libb.a
└── t
    └── a.c
```

Here is the content of each file:

***i.h:***

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f (int);
#define LENGTH 4
```

***b.c:***

```
#include "i.h"

void f (int i)
{
    printf ("from b.c: %d\n", i);
}
```

***a.c:***

```
#include "../i.h"

int main (void)
{
    f (23);
    printf ("%d\n", LENGTH);
}
```

To build `b.o`, I issued: `gcc -c i.h b.c`. To build `libb.a`, I issued: `ar rcs libb.a b.o`.

The command `gcc ../b.o a.c` (when issued from inside `test/t`, produces `a.out` which runs as expected. The problem is when I am trying to link with `libb.a` using: `gcc -L.. -lb a.c` from inside `test/t`. The linker is complaining:

```
$ gcc -L.. -lb a.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccbT50MJ.o: in function `main':
a.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `f'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Don't pass `.h` files as arguments to `gcc`.  There's nothing it can do with them.  The individual C files will include them if they need them.  And put your library options after the C files that depend on them, otherwise it will skip them.

Comment: [Your linkage consumes libraries before the object files that refer to them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43305704/1362568)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the library at the end (after the source file):

```
gcc -L.. a.c -lb
```

The linker searches the library only once when it's seen on the command line. If there were no undefined symbols at that point, it's not looked at again.

From [`ld(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) documentation:

> The linker will search an archive only once, at the location where it
>   is specified on the command line.  If the archive defines a symbol
>   which was undefined in some object which appeared before the archive
>   on the command line, the linker will include the appropriate file(s)
>   from the archive.  However, an undefined symbol in an object appearing
>   later on the command line will not cause the linker to search the
>   archive again.